# How can I get latest version kotlin to update manually?

Tags: android, kotlin

I got an error when try to update the kotlin version automatically, that is have to update manually. But I don't know which version number is latest. So please help me to find out the latest version of option to update. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you can see the latest version in https://kotlinlang.org/

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer. I will check the version and update latest version. #gianhtran